Does Spark use an already defined partitioning when creating a dataset from a rdd
Given the following rdd partitioned by the age of the person, I create a dataset for which I want to output parquet also partitioned by age:
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
      Seq(Person(11, "John Doe"), Person(22, "Jane Doe"), Person(33, "Foo Bar"))
    )
    val rddPartitionedByAge = rdd.keyBy(_.age).partitionBy(new ByAgePartitioner)

    //create dataset from an already partitioned RDD
    import spark.implicits._
    val partitionedDataset = spark.createDataset(rddPartitionedByAge.values)
    partitionedDataset
      .write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .partitionBy("age")  //does spark re-shuffle the data here ? 
      .parquet("./output/datasetFromRdd")


Does spark know about the partitioning of the underlying rdd ?
Does spark re-shuffle the data when writing the parquet with the partition by age ?


What is the question? Title vs text do not match.

As I am on holiday, an answer from memory:

Yes. If no-repartition is set, then it must use same partitioning when DS created. Not a parameter for createDataset api by the way.
Yes. Explicit instruction for api even though we get your point. Check the Spark UI for shuffle- reads and writes. You will see them occuring.

Parquet is columnar so less benefit for partitioning imho.
